# dependsOnMethods and dataprovider method not executed when one of data sets causes a failure

Tags: testng

I am trying to create a testNG test that would depend on a successful execution of the previous test (say I want to create an account then edit some details). I'd like to combine it with data providers. I decided to use dependsOnMethods as this seemed to be logical, however I noticed it behaves other than I would expect. In example below I expect the test "three" to be skipped once and executed once as first set of data provides a pass condition and the other provides a fail condition. Unfortunately it seems I am missing some concept behind "dependsOnMethods". Maybe there is some other way I could do that?
Thanks for any help.

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.Assert;



public class simpleTest {

@DataProvider(name = "provided data")
public static Object[][] data() throws Exception {
       Object[][] data = new Object[][] { 

               {true},
               {false}
               };


       return data;
}


@Test(dataProvider = "provided data")
public void one(boolean cond){
    System.out.println("******** 1");


}
@Test(dataProvider = "provided data")
public void thisfailssometimes(boolean cond){
    System.out.print("******** 2 !!!");
    if (cond) {System.out.println("PASS");}else{System.out.println("FAIL");};
    Assert.assertTrue(cond);


}

@Test(dataProvider = "provided data",dependsOnMethods = {"thisfailssometimes"})
public void three(boolean cond){
    System.out.println("******** 3");


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see the behavior too and I would have expected three to be run once and skipped once too.  The third method is skipped in both cases.  You can probably file a bug or wait for Cedric to reply to the thread.
As a workaround, trying the same flow through factory gives the expected behavior..here's the modified code..

```
 @Factory(dataProvider="provided data")
    public simpleTests(boolean b){
        this.b = b; 
    }
    @DataProvider(name = "provided data")
    public static Object[][] data() throws Exception {
           Object[][] data = new Object[][] { 
                           {true},
                           {false}
                           };


                   return data;
        }

    @Test
    public void one(){
            System.out.println("******** 1");
    }
   @Test
   public void thisfailssometimes(){
       System.out.print("******** 2 !!!");
       if (b) {System.out.println("PASS");}else{System.out.println("FAIL");};
       Assert.assertTrue(b);

            }

   @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"thisfailssometimes"})
   public void three(){
        System.out.println("******** 3");
            }
```

Comment: This works gr8, thanks for prompt reply and for the code example.